# Powershell .txt to CSV Formatting Irregularities

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I have a large number of `.txt` files pulled from pdf and formatted with comma delimiters.

I'm trying to append these text files to one another with a new line between each. Earlier in the formatting process I took multi-line input and formatted it into one line with entries separated by commas.

Yet when appending one txt file to another in a `csv` the previous formatting with many line breaks returns. So my final output is valid `csv`, but not representative of each text file being one line of `csv` entries. How can I ensure the transition from txt to `csv` retains the formatting of the txt files?

I've used `Export-CSV`, `Add-Content`, and the `>>` operator with similar outcomes.

To summarize, individual `.txt` files with the following format:

```
,927,Dance like Misty"," shine like Lupita"," slay like Serena. speak like Viola"," fight like Rosa! ,United States ,16 - 65+
```

Turn into the following when appended together in a `csv` file:

```
,927
,Dance like Misty"," shine like Lupita"," slay like Serena. speak like Viola"," fight like Rosa!
,United States
,16 - 65+
```

**How the data was prepped:**

Removing new lines

```
Foreach($f in $FILES){(Get-Content $f -Raw).Replace("`n","") | Set-Content $f -Force}
```

Adding one new line to the end of each txt file

```
 foreach($f in $FILES){Add-Content -Path $f -value "`n" |Set-Content $f -Force}
```

**Trying to Convert to CSV, one text file per line with comma delimiter:**

```
cat $FILES | sc csv.csv
```

Or

```
 foreach($f in $FILES){import-csv $f -delimiter "," | export-csv $f}
```

Or

```
foreach($f in $FILES){ Export-Csv -InputObject $f -append -path "test.csv"}
```

Return `csv` with each comma separated value on a new line, instead of each txt file as one line.

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Comment: Merill I think we need some more information. Could you show us the code you're using to convert from the text files to the joined CSV? Please try to provide a [mcve] to have the best chance at getting an answer.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart -- updated with additional info: How can I ensure the transition from txt to csv retains the formatting of the txt files?

Comment: @briantist -- updated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by realizing that even though notepad was showing no newlines, there were still hidden return carriage characters. On loading the apparently one line csv files into Notepad++ and toggling "show hidden characters" this oversight was evident.

By replacing both \r and \n characters before converting to CSV,

```
Foreach($f in $FILES){(Get-Content $f -Raw).Replace("\n","").Replace("\r","" | 
Set-Content $f -Force}
```

The CSV conversion process worked as planned using the following

```
cat $FILES | sc final.csv
```

Final verdict -- 
The text file that appeared to be a one line entry ready to become CSV

```
,927,Dance like Misty"," shine like Lupita"," slay like Serena. speak like Viola"," fight like Rosa! ,United States ,16 - 65+
```

Still had return carriage characters between each value. This was made evident by trying another text editor with the feature "show hidden characters."

Comment: Great job! When I do replaces for line endings, I usually use `-replace` operator (which takes a regular expression) instead of the `.Replace()` method. Then I do `-replace '\r?\n'` which means "0 or 1 carriage returns followed by 1 linefeed"; this catches both Windows and Linux line ending styles in one call. Chainging the `.Replace()` method is just fine as well.